# PHP show message box for update query status

Tags: php, mysql, messagebox, dialog

I'm new in PHP, so I'm not sure how to show message box or dialog box containing message to show update query status (the update query is set to work on MYSQL).

--Here is my Code--

```
session_start();
include_once("../classes/cls_main.php");   
$connection = new MainClass();                  
$connection->createConnection();    
$connection->selectDatabase();    

$strSQL = "Update tr_routing set Worktatus = 'Sync' ,Sync_Date = Now() WHERE WorkStatus = 'Done' and UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM ms_user WHERE UserName = '" . $_GET['kode'] . "') ";       

$rs = $connection->CRUD_Data($strSQL);


if(mysql_query($strSQL)){  
    echo "Success update";  
}else{  
    echo "No rows update";  
}  


$connection->closeConnection();
```

--End Of Code--

the PHP is trigger by jScript, the jScript is trigger by button on html file.
Thank You in Advance for answering

Comment: If any advice solve your problem then you should accept that answer by click on right mark.

Answer (score 0):

you may use jquery for this.

```
var result = $.get( "your_query_file.php", function(data) {
   alert( data );
}).fail(function() {
   alert( "error" );
});
```

Comment: I try it, but not work, don't know why, but the problem solved, thank you for the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code to display the message when rows are updated or if they are not

```
<?php
if(mysql_query($strSQL))
{  
   ?>
    <script>
        alert('Rows are updated successfully');
    </script>
<?php
}
else 
{
    ?>
    <script>
        alert('No rows updated');
    </script>
    <?php

}
?>
```